# How to delete specific rows conditionally for many variables in a simple way?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Let's say I have this dataframe (but imagine it with hundreds of variables x, y, etc.).

```
df = data.frame ( x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

and I wish to delete the rows that contain either 1 or 5 in any variable.

I am familiar with the following algorithm:

```
df[!(df$x==1|df$x==5|df$y==1|df$y==5),]
```

But I am looking for a small function that can handle hundreds of variables at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following code:

```r
df = data.frame ( x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,3,4,5))
df[rowSums(df==1|df==5)==0,]
#>   x y
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 4 4 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

```r
df = data.frame ( x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,3,4,5))
df[rowSums(df[-1]==1|df[-1]==5)==0,]
#>   x y
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 4 4 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Not sure why you're omitting the first column?

Comment: I would think `df[rowSums(df %in% c(1, 5)) == 0, ]`

Comment: or this one ```df[!rowSums(df==1 | df==5),]``` or ```df[apply(df!=1 & df!=5, 1, all), ]```

Answer (score 7):

Using `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(!if_any(everything(), ~ .x %in% c(1, 5)))
```

-output

```
  x y
1 2 2
2 3 3
3 4 4
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(flag = if_any(everything(), `%in%`, c(1,5))) %>%
  filter(!flag)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just another base solution:

```
df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% c(1, 5))),]

#>   x y
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```r
df[apply(df, 1, \(x){!any(x %in% c(1,5))}),]
#>   x y
#> 2 2 3
#> 3 3 3
#> 4 4 4
```

In a function:

```r
delete_rows <- function(d, n){
  d[apply(d, 1, \(x){!any(x %in% n)}),]
}
delete_rows(df, c(1,3,4))
#>   x y
#> 5 5 5
```